# deleting a sql dump file

Tags: php, mysql, file-permissions, unlink

I create a csv file with the SQL query:

```
        $sql = "SELECT 'id','username','name','email',
        'phone_number','city',
        'batch','course_type' UNION ALL
        SELECT id, username, name, email,
        phone_number, city, batch, course_type
        FROM users INTO OUTFILE '".$file_path."' ".
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

After causing a browser force-download of this file, I need to delete this file from the /tmp directory. But since, the file is owned by mysql, the php code cannot delete it. How do I change permissions on this file in my code so that the file can be deleted?

Comment: Maybe you can create a file from php? In this case you can place this file where you need and delete it later.

Comment: As a general rule, if you don't have permissions to delete it, then you wont have permissions to change the permissions. Androns solution is probably easiest. Just return the results to php and echo it out to the browser from there, saving the need for a temp file

Answer (score 0):

One solution to do this right, is (This is a rough example of how it could be done):

Return the data from the database as an array, and iterate through it:

```
// tell the browser that this is a download
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=list.csv");

// column separator    
$separator = ';';
// field delimiter
$field_delimiter = '"';
// line end
$line_end = "\r\n";

foreach ($result as $row):

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($row as $item):
        // do not add separator before the first item
        if ($i > 0)
        {
            echo $separator;
        }

        echo $field_delimiter.$item.$field_delimiter;

        $i++;

    endforeach;

    // line end
    echo $line_end;

endforeach;
```

Do not output anything else, just the CSV content.